# Vertical line across multiple line charts with value display for each chart in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I am trying to create an application which will have four line charts on a single form. When user will drag mouse over these charts, there should be one vertical line crossing each chart and the current value will be shown for each chart. Is there any way how this can be done in C#/.NET and WinForms?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at devexpress? https://www.devexpress.com/

Comment: I have the Infragistics package, but even with that I don't know how to do it. Should it be possible with the DevExpress package?

Comment: You can certainly do that with MSChart. Did you add four charts or (recommended) use 4 chartareas in the same chart control? This woudl help to keep the mouse event in one place..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to put your data into **one** MSChart control with four separate  **ChartAreas**.

For this you need to set their positions because the default layout would be 2x2.

Then you add a `VerticalLineAnnotation` and make it **movable**.

In its moving events you trigger the `Paint` event of the chart, where you calculate the necessary data, i.e. the values to display and positions where to display them.

Here is an example:

[image]

The `Paint` event is coded like this:

```
private void chart_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    double xv = VL.X;   // get x-value of annotation
    for (int i = 0; i < chart.ChartAreas.Count; i++)
    {
        ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[i];
        Series s = chart.Series[i];
        int px = (int )ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(xv);
        var dp = s.Points.Where(x => x.XValue >= xv).FirstOrDefault();
        if (dp != null)
        {
            int py = (int )ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[0].YValues[0]) - 20;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dp.YValues[0].ToString("0.00"), 
                                  Font, Brushes.Black, px, py);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of two axis functions to convert between two (of the three) coordinate systems in a chart: We start with data values and go to pixels. The third system is percentages, which we'll meet below when setting up the chartareas..

Also note that for simplicty's sake I assume that there is one Series per ChartArea; so I can use the same index. You could also find the respective Series by seaching for the Series with the right ChartArea.Name field (*).

Feel free to set a different y-position and of course font, formatting etc..

To bring it to live we code these two events:

```
private void chart_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, 
                                              AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
{
    chart.Invalidate();
}

private void chart_AnnotationPositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart.Invalidate();
}
```

The chart setup including test data creation is a little longer..:

First we declare a class level variable for the annotation. Of course we could also grab it from the `chart.Annotations` collection..:

```
VerticalLineAnnotation VL = null;

private void setupbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart.ChartAreas.Clear();
    chart.Series.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas.Add("CA" + (i+1));
        ca.Position = new ElementPosition(0, i*23 + 5, 90, 25);
        Series s = chart.Series.Add("S" + (i+1));
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        s.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;  // make the points stand out
        s.MarkerSize = 3;
        s.ChartArea = ca.Name;  // where each series belongs (*)

        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)  // a few test data
        {
            s.Points.AddXY(j, Math.Sin((( (j + 1) *(i + 1) ) / 55f) * 10f));
        }
    }

    VL = new VerticalLineAnnotation();  // the annotation
    VL.AllowMoving = true;              // make it interactive

    VL.AnchorDataPoint = chart.Series[0].Points[0];  // start at the 1st point
    VL.LineColor = Color.Red;
    VL.IsInfinitive = true;             // let it go all over the chart

    chart.Annotations.Add(VL);
}
```

If you watch the animation closely you will see the values jump; that is because I only have 50 points. If you wanted to display interpolated values you could do that by finding the other neighbouring point and do some simple math. But in many cases this would be nonsense.

Note that I used some 'magic' numbers when setting the `ChartArea.Position`. It is in **percentages** of the Chart and I left a little slack at top and botton and also to the right for the `Legend`..

Comment: This looks like a great solution. Can't wait to test it. Thanks for all the code and samples.

Comment: Just starting to work on it. Was sick for a week. Will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Got it to work. Now I have to build the rest of my application on this. Thank you so much!